# cellForRowAtIndexPath to load 3 cells above and below the visible cells

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uitableview

I know that cellForRowAtIndexPath only loads visible cells. Is there a way to force it so that it loads the 3 cells below and above it?

Comment: This method is almost always the place where the requested cell is configured. Is that what you mean by "load"?  `cellForRowAtIndexPath` doesn't load anything in the sense that it places a cell in the table. It primarily provides a method to the UITableViewController to identify (by reference) a cell that the controller wants to place somewhere (which always happens to be a visible cell). The controller takes care of the cell's presentation.

Comment: What do you need to do during cells loading? Expansive computation? Download from network?

Answer (score 3):

No, `cellForRowAtIndexPath` only loads the current cell.

Your question suggests that you're doing something that is computationally expensive or slow in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. For example, you might be doing lazy loading of images, but also want to "prefetch" some of images you need for candidate "next" cells in order to diminish the user's experience of the lazy loading. Generally, though, you wouldn't actually prefetch the `UITableViewCell` objects, themselves, but rather just the pieces of data that those cells need.

You might need to give us more information about what sort of stuff you feel the need to prefetch, and we can provide better counsel. It's a non-trivial issue, somewhat contingent upon having a well-designed model that your controller uses when presenting the view. You might want to share a little about your model and the nature of the stuff that you want to make sure is on-hand for the previous three and next three cells.

Comment: so I have two types of subclass of UITableViewCell, lets say one is A and one is B. The issue is A is loading an image but when it fails, I want it to show in B layout. How can I do this?

Comment: I'm a blockhead, I would probably would have my fetch routine have a block parameter, so that the caller (the view controller) could indicate what it should do upon completion. I would make sure that that block had a `BOOL success` parameter, so the block could do conditional logic based upon the success or failure of the fetch.

Comment: so you're saying prefetch all of this image first and then have a flag somewhere that tells what cell to use?

Comment: @adit Excellent. No offense intended. If you're comfortable caching, you're half-way there because prefetching is really nothing more than adding to your cache the objects associated with the 3 rows before and 3 rows after the `indexPath` objects in your `tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows`.

Answer (score 1):

UITableViews usually take care themselves of the whole process of deciding when to load specific cells.  They automatically remove invisible cells from it, sometimes storing those cells in an internal reusability queue.

UITableView provides a mechanism you can use to speed up the cell creation process by retrieving pre-alloc'd cells when available.  If you use this method properly you should have no trouble with the scrolling speed in your table views.  To do so, you need to configure the reusabilityIdentifier for a cell on creation, and call the method `-[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:]` when you need a new cell in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` implementation.

It should be feasible for you to have your own queue of reusable and preconfigured cells if you still need more speed - although the advantages you can get from implementing something like this remain to be seen (you'd have more rows ready to use, but would also slow down `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` for the cell being requested).  You would also need to be very careful not to clash with UITableView's standard queue.

Check out [Apple's UITableView reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more info on the reusability mechanism.